# Codeigniter stacking url

Tags: codeigniter, url, jquery

I am having this problem of url stacking up. I used jquery ajax request on my localhost and the url became
localhost/website/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction/mycontroller/mynewfunction instead of
localhost/website/index.php/mycontroller/mynewfunction/para1/para2.

Does anyone know why? I have been trying to fix this problem for the whole day. Everywhere I checked that has a url or link appears to be right.

Comment: Can we see the javascript code with the URL you're posting to? You probably need an absolute URL instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way you're writing the URL in the function, typically I find when I run into this the easiest way to fix it is just to use the base_url function instead of trying to use relative URL's. So something like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url();?>mycontroller/myfunction/para1/para2">Link</a>
```

That way you're always directing back to the base and working from there.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I actually have the same problem but when loading up a view.